# Is there a potential slowdown using too many listeners?

Tags: java, actionlistener

In a program I'm writing, I'll have at least 64 JButtons.  Would it be better to write one ActionListener or have 64 of them, one for each?  I don't think that I'm going to use one listener for each JButton route, but it did make me wonder about something.  Is a there point at which too many listeners can actually impair performance and if there is such a thing, how many would it take?

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html) may be useful.

Comment: IMO I always use one listener for all everything, I usually just change the name for the same listener. This allows other coders who might work with you know what these specific buttons are going to be doing

Comment: To me this question is not specific enough. Is the question about writing 64 different classes? Or is the problem in having 64 object instances? In either case I don't see how this has anything to do with performance, at best it is a question of code readability.

Comment: Gimby, there is an array of 64 JButtons in one JFrame and it was suggested in another post to write an ActionListener for each one.  That just had me wondering if there is a limit to how many listeners there can be before something like a slowdown happens when executing.

Comment: Yes but you don't explain why you think there would be a "slow down". You're asking about hypothetical problems of which you don't even have an inkling of proof that they even exist. So what in your troubled mind would cause a slowdown? Having 64 classes? Having 64 object instances? Having 64 isolated buttons each with one listener registered to them? Of course you are not speaking about 64 buttons, you are speaking about the hypothetical case where you have many more. So how many? A thousand buttons each with exactly one listener?

Comment: No, I don't have an "inkling", just theory.  A comparison is one of the slower functions a computer can do.  So, if it is constantly listening through an ActionListener, it would be reasonable to assume that it would tie up some, even if an insignificant amount, of resources.  That doesn't sound like a big deal.  But, if there are 64 of them, it sounds reasonable that there COULD be a performance hit if Java is trying to check 64 listeners every moment.

Comment: It would make more sense if there is one listener, and then Java figures out which one it is.  But, I don't know.  That is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Each JButton is going to hold a list (or array, or collection or however it is implemented) of references to its listeners while not being aware of listeners for other buttons. When an event happens the button calls to its listeners. So having many listeners for other buttons will not slowdown the calling of the listeners. So no slowdown here.

The only source of slowdown I can foresee are cache misses. Having many listeners with different code would mean more cache misses.

But having a single listener with a lot of convoluted code to handle all cases might be even slower. You still have a lot of bytecode and you may be having a lot more branching than in the case of multiple listeners.

**Conclusion** :
Make your listeners [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). Have different listeners for dealing with different actions and use the same listener for buttons performing a similar action. It will give you both better code and speed.

Answer (score 1):

I would not be so worried about this. I would be worried about the logic in the one listener. It could be get quite complex and long-winded. The overhead of maintenance could be a cause of concern. (But I have no I idea what would go in this *big* listener.)

Small listener are focused and convey intent very clearly. But I agree 64 is a lot.

Comment: The JButtons will be in an array and I'll probably use the getName/setName methods suggested in another post to identify which one was clicked.  I was just curious because one listener per JButton was suggested.